# .NET MAUI Exception Line Number Doesn't Show In AppCenter or StackTrace On Android

Tags: android, maui, stack-trace, debug-symbols, visual-studio-app-center

I am using NET MAUI with .net 7 and Microsoft App Center for Android diagnostics. When in debug mode it works fine and all exceptions sended to App Center has exception Line Numbers. But when I try it on release build with real android devices it sends no LineNumber and limited information about exception.

Debug Build Exception Report Example On Appcenter:

[image: Debug Build Exception Report Example On Appcenter:]

Release Build Exception Report For Same Exception On Appcenter:

[image: Release Build Exception Report For Same Exception On Appcenter:]

I tried to upload symbol files to the AppCenter to fix this but it's not working.

By the way I am not experienced with creating debug symbol files and maybe I am doing something wrong while creating it. The way I do it is;

- Go to the project's obj\Release\net7.0-android\android-arm64\aot folder , select all .so files and zip them
- Upload this file to the Appcenter.

Am I doing something wrong about creating the symbol files and if not how can I get line numbers of exceptions in Appcenter.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any update on this?  We are having the same challenge.

Comment: I think this is the default behavior. As far as I remember, line number are not kept when in Release mode (because of optimizations ?).